# Setting window background JavaDoc in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, colors

I have black background color. How do I change the background color of the window JavaDoc?
[image: screen 1]

**[UPDATE #1]**
similar problem
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=77817&

Comment: you can use Gnome Color chooser in ubuntu see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467359/how-to-change-the-textcolor-of-the-javadoc-view-in-eclipse/26679470#26679470

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors And Fonts > Java > Javadoc View Background

If that doesn't work then you may need to change your "tooltip" colours of your theme for Ubuntu.  It appears that is where it inherits from.

Comment: And where is change the text color?

Comment: I changed the background color and text settings topic. Background color changed, but not text color.

Comment: Ubuntu theme is the answer for hover javadoc in editor and open file list. +1.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Ubuntu 11.04+ and cant easily access the theme editor, Use this:

[how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity)

Comment: I knew my answer would be useful 4 years later!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here to have a properly formattet tooltip (at least for people who use ubuntu and want to have a nice hover tooltip) with html elements like links working is to install libwebkitgtk as it is used by eclipse to show javadoc. It is not preinstalled on e.g. Ubuntu and does not come with eclipse.. use:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

and restart eclipse to have good looking tooltips.