# How to change the textcolor of the JavaDoc view in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I sometimes use the JavaDoc-view in Eclipse. By default it has a black background and a white font. I'd really like to change it to "black on white" (as in the rest of Eclipse).

I only found a way to manipulate the background-color and the font-type. But where can I change the font-color?

[image]

Comment: As your screenshot shows Ubuntu, check if http://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse helps you out.

Comment: @R_User did you find my answer useful?

Comment: You have to award the bounty - because it will expire in an hour..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]You can change it using gnome-color-chooser (i did in ubuntu 14.04)

1. Go to ubuntu software center and install gnome-color-chooser.

2. Go to Specific Tab and tick foreground color and background color, change it to back and white respictively.
The color of javaDoc View is changed.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't this help if you'd change the 'Tooltip' color in Ubuntu at the OS level?
Go to: `System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Colors -> Tooltips`

Comment: I just tried it and can confirm that changing the _Tooltip text color_ in the system settings changes the Javadoc View and Javadoc Tooltip color in Eclipse 4.4 on Windows 7; though you may have to play with `General > Appearance > Theme` if it doesn't work at first. (As a ?bonus it also changes the Heap Status text color :)